# Nullpointer when loading boolean from strings.xml

Tags: android, android-resources

I've added a boolean var to my strings.xml, but when I am trying to retrieve it with the following code.

```
boolean custom = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.customMade);
```

I am getting a nullpointerexception:

```
06-13 11:01:45.983: W/System.err(11951): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 11:01:45.983: W/System.err(11951):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
06-13 11:01:45.993: W/System.err(11951):    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
06-13 11:01:46.003: W/System.err(11951):    at com.koeriers.tools.ConfigFeatures.<init>(ConfigFeatures.java:32)
06-13 11:01:46.003: W/System.err(11951):    at com.koeriers.erasmus.actLogin.<init>(actLogin.java:50)
06-13 11:01:46.003: W/System.err(11951):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-13 11:01:46.013: W/System.err(11951):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-13 11:01:46.013: W/System.err(11951):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
06-13 11:01:46.013: W/System.err(11951):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2163)
06-13 11:01:46.013: W/System.err(11951):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
06-13 11:01:46.023: W/System.err(11951):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
06-13 11:01:46.023: W/System.err(11951):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
06-13 11:01:46.023: W/System.err(11951):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 11:01:46.023: W/System.err(11951):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-13 11:01:46.033: W/System.err(11951):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
06-13 11:01:46.033: W/System.err(11951):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 11:01:46.033: W/System.err(11951):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-13 11:01:46.033: W/System.err(11951):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-13 11:01:46.033: W/System.err(11951):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-13 11:01:46.043: W/System.err(11951):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is where I add the var in my strings.xml:

```
<resources>
<bool name="customMade">true</bool>
</resources>
```

The strings.xml is localized in the res/values/strings.xml folder as usual.
Anyone who can see what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

@edit:

it seems that I've posted not enough code, so here is the whole class in which I trying to retrieve the bool var from my resources:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class ConfigFeatures extends Activity{

//public vars
Cursor mCursor;
public String HeaderIconColor;
public String HeaderStateColor;
public String BackgroundColor;
public String TextColor;
public String DateColor;
public String OrderColorOne;
public String OrderColorTwo;
public int Mijlpaal1;
public int Mijlpaal2;
public Boolean Ritten;
public Boolean Handtekening;
public Boolean Foto;
public Boolean WijzigOrderDetail;
public Boolean Firma;
public Boolean LocatieGegevens;
public int LocatieInterval;

public ConfigFeatures(){
    //initialize the vars

    try {
        boolean custom = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.customMade);
        if (custom) {
            DefaultSettings();
        } else {
            try{
                mCursor = Session.globalTDBAdapter().getData("tbl_Setting", new String[]{TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_HEADERICONCOLOR,
                        TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_HEADERSTATECOLOR,TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_BACKGROUNDCOLOR,
                        TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_TEXTCOLOR,TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_DATECOLOR,
                        TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_ORDERCOLORONE,TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_ORDERCOLORTWO,
                        TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_MIJLPAAL1, TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_MIJLPAAL2,
                        TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_RITTEN, TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_HANDTEKENING,
                        TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_FOTO,TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_FIRMA,
                        TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_WIJZIGORDERDETAIL,TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_LOCATIEGEGEVENS,
                        TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_LOCATIEINTERVAL});

                if (mCursor == null){
                    DefaultSettings();
                } else {
                    this.HeaderIconColor = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_HEADERICONCOLOR));
                    if (this.HeaderIconColor.equals("")){
                        this.HeaderIconColor = "#FFFFFF";
                    }
                    this.HeaderStateColor = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_HEADERSTATECOLOR));
                    if (this.HeaderStateColor.equals("")){
                        this.HeaderStateColor = "#FF8000";
                    }
                    this.BackgroundColor = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_BACKGROUNDCOLOR));
                    if (this.BackgroundColor.equals("")){
                        this.BackgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
                    }
                    this.TextColor = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_TEXTCOLOR));
                    if (this.TextColor.equals("")){
                        this.TextColor = "#000000";
                    }
                    this.DateColor = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_DATECOLOR));
                    if (this.DateColor.equals("")){
                        this.DateColor = "#808080";
                    }
                    this.OrderColorOne = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_ORDERCOLORONE));
                    if (this.OrderColorOne.equals("")){
                        this.OrderColorOne = "#EBE3E3";
                    }
                    this.OrderColorTwo = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_ORDERCOLORTWO));
                    if (this.OrderColorTwo.equals("")){
                        this.OrderColorTwo = "#FFFFFF";
                    }
                    this.Mijlpaal1 = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_MIJLPAAL1));
                    this.Mijlpaal2 = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_MIJLPAAL2));
                    this.Ritten = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_RITTEN)).contains("0");
                    this.Handtekening = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_HANDTEKENING)).contains("0");
                    this.Foto = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_FOTO)).contains("0");
                    this.WijzigOrderDetail = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_WIJZIGORDERDETAIL)).contains("0");
                    this.Firma = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_FIRMA)).contains("0");
                    this.LocatieGegevens = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_LOCATIEGEGEVENS)).contains("0");
                    this.LocatieInterval = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TDBAdapterSingleton.KEY_LOCATIEINTERVAL));
                    mCursor.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                mCursor.close();
            } finally {
                DefaultSettings();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        DefaultSettings();
    }
}
public void DefaultSettings(){
    this.HeaderIconColor = "#FFFFFF";
    this.HeaderStateColor = "#3DA2C8";
    this.BackgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    this.TextColor = "#000000";
    this.DateColor = "#808080";
    this.OrderColorOne = "#3DA2C8";
    this.OrderColorTwo = "#FFFFFF";
    this.Mijlpaal1 = 1;
    this.Mijlpaal2 = 2;
    this.Ritten = false;
    this.Handtekening = true;
    this.Foto = true;
    this.WijzigOrderDetail = true;
    this.Firma = true;
    this.LocatieGegevens = true;
    this.LocatieInterval = 1000 * 60 * 5;
}
```

}

Comment: where do use this boolean custom = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.customMade); in your activity class?

Comment: I am using the boolean just 2 lines below that line of code. For an if statement

Comment: do you use the same in activity class or non activity class

Comment: the class is a not an activity class

Comment: Then that is the issue my friend, it has to be an activity class OR you can pass an activity reference then do something like this: `activity.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.customMade);` aside from that everything looks fine.

Comment: you have to use the context passed to the non activity class and use the same to getResources

Comment: made it an activity class, but still getting the nullpointer

Comment: oh boy... it doesn't work like that, it has to be an active activity, not just the class, because `getResources()` gets the actual live resources of the activity.

Comment: check my posted reply. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083164/nullpointer-when-loading-boolean-from-strings-xml/17083776#17083776

Comment: My bad... I know what you mean. Should have implemented the onCreate. And it works right now. So thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
public ConfigFeatures(Activity activity){
    boolean custom = activity.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.customMade);
```

and the activity calling `ConfigFeatures()` make it like this `ConfigFeatures(getBaseContext()`

Comment: that would do the trick too indeed, but I've implemented the onCreate and it does the job too. So thanks a lot..

Comment: you are welcome, however I would recommend you pass an activity/context, and not implement an activity where an activity is not really there, I think that may have unpredictable side-effects, it just seem iffy. Cheers and good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I you wanted something into strings.xml, you should have wrote

```
getResources().getString(R.string.customMade);
```

This is where your NullPointerException comes from. On the other hand, don't think you are able to put boolean or other values into strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

The `getResources()` returns null, because it cannot find your file.

The first obvious one is you are pointing to `R.bool` while your bool is in `R.string`

Either put your bool in a bools.xml or use R.string (better just use bools.xml).

**Note:**

@Raghunandan asks a volid question because it is also possible `getResources()` is missing context.

Depending on where you place the call, `getResource()` also returns null when you dont pass your Context as reference. For example: `getApplicationContext().getResources();`

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <item type="bool" name="customMade">true</item>
</resources>
```

Then in the code get the value by doing this:

```
boolean custom= getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.customMade);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have this /res/values/bools.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<bool name="customMade">true</bool>
</resources>
```

To refer

```
Resources res = getResources();
boolean custom  = res.getBoolean(R.bool.customMade);
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Bool

If you are using getResources() in a non activity class you need the context . pass the context of the activity to the non activity class constructor and use the same

Form you activity

```
   new  ConfigFeatures(ActivityName.this);
```

In your non activity clas

```
   Context mContext;  
   public ConfigFeatures(Context c){
     mContext =c; // use the context to get resources

   }
```

Comment: I doubt that creating an object of Resources will do the trick, because I am doing the same thing. Only now I am doing it in 1 line of code. But I will try this solution

Comment: @user where do you call the same in your activity class or a class that doe snot extend activity?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing your resources too early, as indicated by this line in the stacktrace:

```
 06-13 11:01:46.003: W/System.err(11951):    at com.koeriers.erasmus.actLogin.<init>(actLogin.java:50)
```

That means the initialization code of your `actLogin`. Move your member variable init code that requires accessing resources to `onCreate()`.

-- edit after question updated

Your `ConfigFeatures` is not an activity even though it extends it. It therefore does not have a valid `Context` for `getResources()` to work. Solution: Remove `extends Activity` and add a `Context` parameter to the constructor, calling `getResources()` on the passed-in context.